# Python selenium how to execute execute_script on a JavaScript element with arguments

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to download documents from a website.
When I inspect the element in my browser, this is what I get:

```
<td width="3%" align="left" id="tdvPDF0" colspan="3">
<a href="#" onclick="javaScript:downloadClicked('JRAOB2SNRXEAPX2', 0, 'PDF'); return false;" onmouseover="window.status='CTNF'; return true" onmouseout="window.status=''; return true">PDF</a>
/&nbsp;
<a href="#" onclick="javaScript:downloadClicked('JRAOB2SNRXEAPX2', 0, 'XML_LINK'); return false;" onmouseover="window.status='CTNF'; return true" onmouseout="window.status=''; return true">XML</a>
/&nbsp;
<a href="#" onclick="javaScript:downloadClicked('JRAOB2SNRXEAPX2', 0, 'DOCX'); return false;" onmouseover="window.status='CTNF'; return true" onmouseout="window.status=''; return true">DOCX</a>
</td>
```

I would like download all three documents, i.e. the PDF, XML, and DOCX.
This JavaScript can accept three arguments. In this case they are:
1. JRAOB2SNRXEAPX2 (string)
2. 0 (integer)
3. PDF (string)

I have no idea of how to ascertain the correct input for the first argument (in this example: "JRAOB2SNRXEAPX2")

I would like to have my code work regardless of the first argument.

Previously, when I've encountered JavaScript functions I used the following:

```py
driver.execute_script(name_of_JavaScript_script())
```

that would generally work, however I have never encountered a JavaScript with arguments as in this case, e.g. downloadClicked('JRAOB2SNRXEAPX2', 0, 'PDF')

I tried the following without success:

```py
driver.execute_script(downloadClicked('JRAOB2SNRXEAPX2', 0, 'PDF'))
driver.execute_script(downloadClicked(''JRAOB2SNRXEAPX2', 0, 'PDF''))
driver.execute_script(downloadClicked('JRAOB2SNRXEAPX2', 0, 'PDF')); return false;
```

and many other similar options.

I've also tried:

```py
javascript = driver.find_element_by_id('tdvPDF0').click()
driver.execute_script(javascript)
```

In addition I've tried:

```py
driver.find_element_by_id('tdvPDF0').click()
```

The code for the function currently looks like this:

```py
def private_pair_ifw_downloader(driver, application_number, pause=1):
    private_pair_enter_application(driver, application_number)
    time.sleep(pause)
    driver.execute_script('submitTab("ifwtab")')
    time.sleep(pause)

    driver.execute_script('"javaScript:downloadClicked(''JRAOB2SNRXEAPX2', 0, 'PDF''); return false;"')
```

I expect for the code to invoke the JavaScript function which in turn should download the PDF file however, I received the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Workspaces/patents_repo/USPTO_scraper/uspto_private_pair_scraper.py", line 41, in 
    private_pair_ifw_downloader(driver, '15723211')
  File "C:\Workspaces\patents_repo\utils\web_utils.py", line 211, in private_pair_ifw_downloader
    driver.execute_script('"javaScript:downloadClicked(''JRAOB2SNRXEAPX2', 0, 'PDF''); return false;"')
  File "C:\Users\eitan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Users\eitan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\eitan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is wrap your input to execute_script in double quotes.

```
driver.execute_script("downloadClicked('JRAOB2SNRXEAPX2', 0, 'PDF');")
```

Comment: How do I handle the issue with regards to the first argument? Do I have to input some type of string here? What do I do if I don't know the string?

Comment: you can pass the values as arguments as part of execute_script.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the string you can try something like:

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("a[onclick*=PDF]").onclick()')
```